# Configuring ansible to use python3 on remote targets

Tags: ansible

I've been looking into attempting to get ansible to use python3 on remote targets, in order to run playbooks against them, however, simply running a playbook against a target with python3 installed fails with the error message:

```
"/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python: not found\r\n"
```

Looking for answers to this online only seem to discuss configuring ansible on the host to use python3 rather than the remote. Is it possible to configure the remote to use python3 rather than 2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the `ansible_python_interpreter` variable to tell Ansible which version of Python to use.  You can set this globally, as C. Dodds has suggested in their answer, but it generally makes more sense to set this as a per-host inventory variable. E.g., using a YAML inventory:

```
all:
  hosts:
    myhost:
      ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
```

Or using an ini-style inventory:

```
myhost ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```

And of course you can set this per-hostgroup if you have several hosts that require the same configuration.

This is discussed in the [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/python_3_support.html).

Answer (score 4):

Adding the argument "-e 'ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3'" was the solution to this:

```
ansible-playbook sample-playbook.yml -e 'ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3'
```